# Nginx and gunicorn are running but i get 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) error

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I followed digital oceans instructions to deploy my django app. gunicorn and nginx are running but when im getting bad gateway error.

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.69.216.111;

    root /Owia/;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /Owia;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/admin/Owia/Owia.sock;
    }


     location /static/admin {
     root /Owia/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/;

    }

     location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
     expires 365d;
     add_header Pragma public;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
     }
 }
```

and this is my gunicorn conf:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling Owia"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid www-data
setgid www-data

chdir /Owia



exec venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/admin//Owia.sock Owia.wsgi:application
```

Should i check somewhere else? what can be wrong?

Comment: are you quite sure that gunicorn is running? Your gunicorn configuration seems rather improbable. For example 'chdir /Owia' ? and --bind unix:/home/admin//Owia.sock

Comment: What happens if you run the gunicorn command manually